# Choosing a scheduling mechanism

Tags: .net, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

As part of a web app that relies on different data feeds from the internet, I need to create a component that pulls data from different places over the net, and makes them available for my web app.
It has a list of resources to fetch, and a different timing for each resource. In example, it needs to pull an RSS feed every 1 hour, and call an certain REST API every 30 min.

I have already implemented the fetching part. I am now wandering how to implement the scheduling part.

I know I can use windows scheduled tasks, or windows services, and I have read answers about this topic, but they are generally speaking.
I was wandering what do you think best suits my specific case. (other options are welcomed as well)
Also, How would you recommend to implement the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: This is not an alternative to using a Windows Service or a Timer Job, right? 
As I understand, this is the scheduling part of my Windows Service or Timer Job.
Am I correct?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Quartz is a mechanism that enables you to execute tasks/method according to a specific schedule. This has nothing to do with the execution package form (application/windows service). A timer is a very primitive method of executing a task/method in predefined intervals.

Answer (score 0):

A mistake I've often seen made in similar cases is to try and make everything part of the same Web Application. Assuming your "data" pulled from "different places" is flat and simple enough so it can be stored to the filesystem, or a database (vs. being of such nature that must reside in-memory -- e.g. a complex interconnected graph of objects), I would make your "crawler" a separate process.

Now, should that process be a simple Command Line, activated by the Windows Task Scheduler, or a Windows Service, activated by something like Quartz.Net, really depends on how much stuff it has to initialize every time it starts and how often it needs to wake up. To give the two extremes, if it runs once a day, make it a Command Line app. If it runs every 5 seconds, and it takes it 3 seconds to start-up and JIT all its code, make it a Windows Service. If you ever want it to be activated by a user and its reaction time must be instantaneous, again make it a Windows Service.

You can always start with Command Line and move to Services when the need arises, you won't have to reimplement much, and your architecture will end up being simpler if you keep the processing and the scheduling parts separate, which is what Command Line approach forces on you.